# System hit counter SaaS - Via TXT - Imagecopymerge

Tags: php, image

I am doing an hit counter (view) system, and now I need to find a way to merge all number images into one to be possible to embed in another pages, could someone help me out?

Here is the code I have:

```
$number = trim(file_get_contents('visitas.txt'));

$file = 'visitas.txt'; 
$views = file_get_contents ($file); 
$fdata = intval($views)+1; 
file_put_contents($file, $fdata);


$array = str_split($number);
if(!empty($array)){
  foreach($array as $single){
        echo '<img style="height:20px" src="'.$single.'.png">';
  }
}else{
        echo '<img src="0.png">';
}

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('sample.jpg'));
```

At the moment everything is working, each refresh is counting and sum the number writed by image, but I need to embed this counter in another pages, something like:

```
<img src='https://countersite.com.br/img-counter-385503.jpg'>
```

Here is a image of the counter working:

[image: counter]

UPDATED

I need help to merge the image already created with the numbers (0.png, 1.png...) into one image (counter1.png).

Comment: If the counter outputs HTML, you can't put it in a `<img />`-tag. Just include the file: `<?php require('counter.php') ?>`. If you want to load the counter as an image, you need to dynamically create the image and only output the image contents (with the correct image header and without any HTML). I would also recommend against storing the counter in a text file. The file system is slow. On high load (simultaneous requests), you can end up with  race conditions.  It's better to use a database or some persistent in-memory cache.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, I need to embed the counter in another domains so I cant use require('counter.php'), Right, could you show me how can I create the image after or inside the foreach?

Comment: You need to google how to dynamically create the image. It's not that trivial that I can show it quickly here on SO. I would need to look it up myself. But you can do in PHP using GD or Imagick. Another alternative is that you include the script using an iframe on the other site: `<iframe src="http://yoursite/counter.php"></iframe>` and style the iframe to be the correct size to fit the counter. Then you should be able to use what you got.

Comment: Yea I am already did, I am having trouble to create the image inside the foreach which already create an image, Isn't a simple image creation because its not directly I dont know if I need to create the full image (with the numbers images) inside the foreach or I need to do that after

Comment: It is possible to do with image? I cant use iframe

Comment: If you're going to generate an image, then you won't "put it in your foreach". You need to get the count, generate a new image, add the numbers to the image and output it. You need to rewrite your code. If you can't use iframes, then this is the only way. Search for something like: "php create image with text" and read through a few tutorials to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: Each number has an image, it will have diferent styles of images representing numbers, so that why I created the code with foreach. What do you think if I merge all images (numbers) created into one image and save it? something with imagecopymerge function, is it possible to do?

Comment: That's what I mean by "generating a dynamic image". First you check if an image with that number exists, if it does, just load the existing image data and output that. If not, you generate it, save the image (so you can reuse it without needing to regenerate it) and then output it. If you never want to reuse the images, then just skip the saving part. Even the saving the image contents would probably be faster and safer to do in some persistent cache, rather than using the file system.

Comment: I am worried about the consume server to do all this, do you think is it's worth save each image and store it? the system already do : 1. sum +1 into txt.file / 2. create custom image with the total (imagine doing this with 100 sites, getting views each second).

Comment: Hey @MagnusEriksson I found the solution for this, but got only one detail, could you help me a sec? I know you gonna find an easy solution for this hehe

Comment: You should post it as a new question containing all necessary information.

Comment: Ok I will, if you can wait 5 mins will be awesome, because you know all the history hehe, could you?

Comment: No promises. Just post a new question with all relevant info and anyone can help out.

Comment: I just looked at the question and it's very unclear (which is a valid reason for down voting). They also gave you the same advice as I did here (create the image separately and don't output the img tag). Not to be mean, but I think you either need to hire someone or learn more of the basics first, because you don't really seem to know enough to even understand our comments.